# Using Django ORM as a multi-process lock across hosts

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm running Django on several web hosts connected to a common database server. The database contains a simple table of pending jobs. e.g.

```
class Job(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, help_text='task to do')
    worker = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, help_text='globally unique host name')
```

How would I use Django's ORM to query a pending job (where worker is null) and set the worker name atomically, so no two Django processes would accidentally grab the same job (i.e. avoid a race condition)?

Ideally, I'd simply want to wrap by query/update inside a table lock, but Django's ORM doesn't seem to have this feature built-in.

Comment: Have you looked at using Celery for this sort of distributed task management, rather than trying to build it yourself?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Yes. I'm currently using Celery for many tasks, and I don't care much for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, Celery would be the best tool for this. If you don't want to use Celery:

- If you are on latest Django, use [select_for_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) to query your Job and then fill up the worker field. That's the "Table Lock" you wanted in Django ORM. It only lock the rows affected, so it's better than table lock by allowing more concurrency.
- If you are on a older version where `select_for_update()` is not available, implement a "Lock Table" (as easy as 10 lines) to protect your critical sections.

Comment: For the record, Celery doesn't support this out of the box. You need to use a custom function decorator and memcache to get this functionality with Celery.